# Powershell, program exe with if else

Tags: powershell

I've generated this code to run a program (MetaX) when a file extension is present in a folder.. but when it finds x amount of file extension it tried to run the program x amount of times.

```
$Files3 = "C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\MASTER_FOLDER\3_FINISHED"
$MetaX = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MetaX"
$MetaXTVShows = "C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\MASTER_FOLDER\2_TEMPORARY\TV_SHOWS"
$MetaXExtensions = @(".mp4")

Set-Location $MetaXTVShows
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {
If ($MetaXExtensions -contains $_.Extension)
{& $MetaX\metax.exe /T /A $MetaXTVShows /AT $Files3 /C}
Else {}
}
```

I believe it is something to do with the if else function but I could be wrong. I originally tried for each then tried where-object.

Is there any other alternative to this as running the program 5 times due to been 5 extensions in the folder it is searching doesn't work well with the software?

Comment: So do you need to run `$MetaX\metax.exe` against each `.mp4` files found in `$MetaXTVShows`? I assume this is what you mean that you have 5 files with `.mp4` in that folder so for each of those files, you need to run the process against those?

Comment: Hi juice, no, So basically when I run metax it will look through the entire directory and put meta data on all the files within one window and move to another directory as I have say 5 .mp4 flies in the folder it is trying to run the program 5 times as it has identified 5 .mp4 files in the first instance, the remaining 4 times of the program obviously can’t find the data now as it’s been moved.. it only requires to be open 1 time regardless of how many .mp4 files are in the folder if that makes sence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is returning more than one file with that extension. Then you are executing the program each time that extension appears. Simply check if the extension exists, ie true or false. Based on that result, execute your program.

Comment: thanks, ill have a dig and see what i can come up with and post my results.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it partially to work Thanks Keltan for the advice..

```
$Files3 = "C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\MASTER_FOLDER\3_FINISHED"
$MetaX = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MetaX"
$MetaXTVShows = "C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\MASTER_FOLDER\2_TEMPORARY\TV_SHOWS"
$MetaXExtensions = @(".mp4")
$ContainsTrue = $MetaXExtensions -contains $_.Extension

Set-Location $MetaXTVShows
If ($ContainsTrue -eq $false)
    {& "C:\Program Files (x86)\MetaX\metax.exe" /T /A $MetaXTVShows /AT $Files3 /C}
Else {"NOTHING"}
```

Works fine to some respect but it doesnt look at *.mp4 in the folder and itll still run the program if nothing is inside, one thing im confussed upon is the $false and $true.. id have though on the line

```
If ($ContainsTrue -eq $false)
```

would have been True?

Comment: You should only answer your own questions with **working solutions** this is not helpful for any follow-up readers. `$_.Extension` is only valid inside a `{ }` of a pipe (ForEach-Object/Where-Object)

Answer (score 0):

IIUR you want to run metax.exe once provided there is at least one .mp4 file in the path:

```
$Files3 = "C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\MASTER_FOLDER\3_FINISHED"
$MetaX = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MetaX"
$MetaXTVShows = "C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\MASTER_FOLDER\2_TEMPORARY\TV_SHOWS"
$MetaXExtensions = @("*.mp4")
Set-Location $MetaXTVShows

if ((Get-ChildItem $MetaXExtensions).count -ge 1){
    & $MetaX\metax.exe /T /A $MetaXTVShows /AT $Files3 /C
}
```

Comment: I wanted to point out something since `$MetaXExtensions` is not in this answer but the OP has as `@(".mp4")` it will need converted to a string i.e. `$MetaXExtensions = [string]$MetaXExtensions` before it'll work properly in this answer or else just use `-Filter "*.mp3"` or set `$MetaXExtensions = "*.mp3"` instead of the array object or whatever. Other than that, it seems like this should resolve the problem fully for the OP so good idea with the count comparison in the if block.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT good catch, thanks for the hint. Changed the script.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got my head round it.. first went for true or false and then dropped upon the Test-Path function, had a little play around and managed to get it to work for this instance. I think if I was searching for something more complex then this would'nt work which I have found on another problem im having (different question altogether will put another post for this)

```
$MetaX = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MetaX"
$MetaXMovies = "C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\MASTER_FOLDER\2_TEMPORARY\MOVIES"
$MetaXTVShows = "C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\MASTER_FOLDER\2_TEMPORARY\TV_SHOWS"
$MetaXExtensions = "*.mp4"
$Files3 = "C:\Users\BRACEGIRDLE\Favorites\Desktop\MASTER_FOLDER\3_FINISHED"

If (Test-Path $MetaXMovies\$MetaXExtensions)
    {& "C:\Program Files (x86)\MetaX\metax.exe" /V /A $MetaXMovies /AT $Files3 /C | Out-Null}
   Else {}
If (Test-Path $MetaXTVShows\$MetaXExtensions)
    {& "C:\Program Files (x86)\MetaX\metax.exe" /T /A $MetaXTVShows /AT $Files3 /C | Out-Null}
   Else {}
```

Many thanks for all you're help, im enjoying learning powershell